# excel 2007 date custom function

Tags: excel, function, date

I have the following problem. I have a gantt-diagramm in excel which looks like this:

```
SD  M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9
A1  |||||||
A2         |||||||||||||
A3    |||||||||||
A4          ||||||||||||
A5              ||||||||||||||
```

and I want to highlight the column which represents the current month. So let's say the start date for the project is somewhere in march then column M2 should be highlighted. I wanted to use conditional formatting but I could not find a useful function to find out if I am two months in the project or not. I want to write a custom function to calculate exactly that and the column should then look like this:

```
SD  M1 M2[M3] M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9
A1  |||||[||]
A2       [||]|||||||||||
A3    |||[||]|||||
A4       [  ] ||||||||||||
A5       [  ]     ||||||||||||||
```

Any hints?

Comment: If you are in March, why do you highlight M2 not M3? Which leads to the question - where do you store the start date of your project - without that piece of info you will not be able to do anything.

Comment: Yes right and right. I added "SD" the start date is saved there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something. A user defined function to calculate days, weeks, months or years between two dates:

```
Function DATEINTERVALL(interval As String, date1 As Date, date2 As Date)
  DATEINTERVALL = DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2, 2)
End Function
```